# sed replacement does not work

Tags: bash, sed

I have trouble using sed.
I need to replace some lines in very deprecated HTML sites which consist of many files.
My script does not work and I do not why. When I tried to find exact pattern with Netbeas it worked.

```
find . -type f -name "*.htm?" -exec sed -i -r 's/ing\. Šuhajda Dušan\, Mírová 767\, 518 01 Dobruška\, \+420 737 980 333\,/REPLACEMENT/g' {} \;
```

Where is the mistake?
Is there an alternative to replace text without searching regular expression but plain text?
Thanks for any respond.

Comment: Your `sed` command works for me. Is it possible that your string spans more than one line? If so, the `sed` command would have to be more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is an easy command line tool called **replace**, syntax is like:

```
replace "string 1" "string 2" -- *.html
```

Comment: Thanks. Next time I search repositories before I ask a question.

Comment: Note that it is a part of mysql client, not of coreutils or separate package.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to escape comma since it not special.

```
find . -type f -iname "*.htm?" -exec sed -i.bak -r 's/ing\. Šuhajda Dušan, Mírová 767, 518 01 Dobruška, \+420 737 980 333,/REPLACEMENT/g' "{}" +;
```